# SQL : comparing two values in a table to a third in a different table

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables with some train information.

- trainStation (station_code, city, state)
- departures (id_departure, origin_station_code, destination_station_code)

Is it possible to find out how many departures are within the same state?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Sure...

```
Select count(*) NbrDepInCA
from departures d join trainStation s 
   on s.station_code = d.origin_station_code
Where s.State = 'CA'
```

and, as suggested by @Katteract, to get count for all states (that have at least one departure)

```
Select s.State, count(*) NbrDepInState
from departures d join trainStation s 
   on s.station_code = d.origin_station_code
Group by s.State
```

Comment: Or use a `GROUP BY s.State` to find the count for all states.

Answer (score 0):

In `PostgreSQL` you can use something like this SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS count FROM departures d
JOIN trainStation t1 ON t1.station_code = d.origin_station_code
JOIN trainStation t2 ON t2.station_code = d.destination_station_code
WHERE t1.state = t2.state
```